# Compute stress tensor in finite element simulation

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, elasticity, stress-strain

I have implemented a finite element simulation using a tetrahedral mesh that minimizes a linear elasticity potential energy. Among the main quantities I compute for the simulation is the deformation gradient $F$ for each tetrahedron, from which I can then compute an elastic energy that I can minimize with respect to nodal positions.

I'm having trouble to understand how to compute "the stress tensor", the thing usually denoted as $\sigma$ which is apparently just a 3x3 matrix. This is one of those derived quantities that I have very little intuition of, since I don't even need to use in my finite element simulation to compute useful results, but I'm trying to understand it since many textbooks mention it. I understand the elastic energy and the deformation gradient of a tetrahedron. Is there a way to compute the stress tensor $\sigma$ for a tetrahedron using its deformation gradient $F$?

Comment: [Tensors aren't really matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20437/25301) (see why stress is a tensor [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/152927/25301)).

Comment: I know there is a difference. I just wanted to make my question very concrete and specific in terms of input - output. I want to compute 9 numbers for the stress tensor, I have access to the elastic energy (1 number) and deformation gradient (9 numbers) for a single tetrahedron. How do I do it?

Comment: *is apparently a 3x3 matrix* strongly suggests you don't recognize or understand the difference, I'm pointing you to a resource to fill that gap.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Sure you can compute the stress tensor from the deformation gradient tensor.  For small strains, this is just Hooke's Stress-Strain Law.

Comment: On behalf of [@user3408085](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/198084/user3408085): http://www.cns.gatech.edu/PHYS-4421/lautrup/2.8/stress.pdf