# Are particles in a perfect fluid in random motion?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stochastic-processes, randomness

A perfect fluid has no heat conduction, but it exerts pressure in all directions (according to stress-energy-momentum tensor).

If it does not conduct heat, then it means it does not have random motion.

How can it exert pressure if it does not have random motion?

Comment: Perfect fluid is an *abstraction*. As a mathematical model it does not have “particles” as entities within this model.

Comment: Probably useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/152927/25301